# jq: Cannot index array with string "0"

Tags: jq

There's "0" in a JSON giving me trouble, I'm trying to grab the value at:

> **response > data > sessions > 0 > user**

The code I used was:

```
jq -r '.response.data.sessions."0".user'
```

The terminal returns: **jq: error (at :1): Cannot index array with string "0"**

I also tried:

```
jq -r '.response.data.sessions.0.user'
```

The terminal returned: **jq: error: syntax error, unexpected LITERAL, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at , line 1:
.response.data.sessions.0.user**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can use like this

https://jqplay.org/s/nYlPohfTdZ

```
.response.data.sessions[0].user
```